# How to make Object Constraint Transformations work across axes?

Tags: transforms, constraints

In the example below, the transformation from X to X works. The monkey follows the torus when I move the torus.

However a transformation from X to Z doesn't work.  I move the torus & the monkey stays in the same spot, instead of moving. Why? Is there something wrong with my transformation settings?

[image: Transformation works on the same axes, like above, but doesn't work across different axes like below. Why not?]

Transformation works on the same axes, like above, but doesn't work across different axes like below. Why not?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first image, you are applying X axis location to X axis location.  In the second image, you are applying Z axis location to Z axis location, but the Z min and max on the map from is not set (it is 0-0).

If you want to map from X to Z, change the Z source axis to X; if you want to map from Z to Z, change the Z min and max to something like -5, 5.

Comment: I had no clue that I had to change the Z source axis from the dropdown. Thank you.